# Community Wiki questions about modes

Tags: discussion

Every other day, a new question about modes arises. Or better the same question rephrased, some variation of "are [mode] and [parent major scale] the same?".

Would it make sense to build some community wiki Q/A base, and to point the new users there every time, rather than fragmentise the knowledge about over every single key people ask for?

One answer per mode with song examples and chord/melody outlines would be very helpful I think.

The concept applies to other tags of course, for instance the infamous "why does this chord progression work" - *because your ears like it!*

Comment: I think it would be better to start looking for duplicates or a canonical question rather than a wiki.There are a lot of questions coming in that we've answered before.

Comment: "Why does this chord progression work", or any "why does ... work" really means "what does this chord progression do harmonically" or "what harmonic patterns can be fitted over this chord progression". But the posters are not to blame for their clumsy wording. "Why does X work" is the commonly used idiom for asking the question. It's like "how do you do" - it doesn't _literally_ mean "how do you do". As an expert you should know this by now. Why don't you go and improve the questions, if you think the wording could be better?